# Passing a python output to Bash script variable

Tags: python, bash

```
#!/bin/bash
data=$(curl -s -X GET $api_end_point)
echo $data
res=$(curl -s -X GET  $api_end_point | python -c "import sys,   json;pretty_data= json.load(sys.stdin);pretty_data[sys.argv[1]]=sys.argv[2];print pretty_data" edgeServerIP test)
echo $res
```

`echo $res` prints nothing while `$data` and `print pretty_data` prints what is expected json, what is wrong with this code?

Comment: Portability note: this won't work on systems where `python` is Python 3. You need parentheses for the `print` statement.

Comment: Maybe that's actually the cause of the problem? Python will print an error to stderr though, so I'd expect that you'd see that. Apart from that I can't reproduce this error; this works fine for me: `res=$(curl -s -X GET https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1 | python -c "import sys, json; pretty_data = json.load(sys.stdin); pretty_data[sys.argv[1]] = sys.argv[2]; print(pretty_data)" edgeServerIP test) && echo $res`.

Comment: I have tried with python3 too.I am facing the same problem.Please note that expectation is json to be printed 3 times in the console, it must be from data,pretty_data(python) and res.@Thomas, are you seeing the same?

Comment: No, you should expect it to be printed only _two_ times. The `res=$(...)` line should not print anything, because the output from the Python code is captured in the `res` variable.

Comment: oh !missed this part.Thanks for saving my time.This was so silly

Comment: BTW, using variable references without double-quotes can cause weird problems. For example, use `echo "$data"` instead of `echo $data`, `curl -s -X GET  "$api_end_point"` instead of `curl -s -X GET  $api_end_point`, etc.

Comment: @GordonDavisson, understood.Thanks